# Batch Avidemux - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: windows, batch, matroska, avidemux

I'm trying to make a batch file that runs through a set of `mkv` files and hardsubs the embedded subtitles into outputted `mp4` files, using Avidemux and MKVToolNix. Here is my batch file:

```
set avidemux="C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\avidemux2_cli.exe"
set mkvextract="C:\Program Files (x86)\MKVToolNix\mkvextract.exe"

::avidemux options
set in=.mkv
set out=_subbed.mp4
set vcodec=x264
set vbr=1500
set acodec=ac3
set abr=320

::mkvextract options
set subtrack=2

for /R %%F in (*%in%) do (
::extract subs
%mkvextract% tracks "%%F" %subtrack%:"%%~dpnF.ass"
::extract up to 20 fonts
%mkvextract% attachments "%%F" 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
::generate file referencing subs and fonts
set dir=%%~dpF
echo.^<?xml version="1.0"?^>>filters.js
echo.^<filters FilterNumber="1"^>>>filters.js
echo.  ^<Filter Tag="65" Conf="ASS/SSA Subtitles"^>>>filters.js
echo.    ^<Parameters Number="7"^>>>filters.js
echo.      ^<font_scale^>1.000000^</font_scale^>>>filters.js
echo.      ^<line_spacing^>0.100000^</line_spacing^>>>filters.js
echo.      ^<top_margin^>0^</top_margin^>>>filters.js
echo.      ^<bottom_margin^>0^</bottom_margin^>>>filters.js
echo.      ^<subfile^>%%~dpnF.ass^</subfile^>>>filters.js
echo.      ^<fonts_dir^>%dir:~0,-1%^</fonts_dir^>>>filters.js
echo.      ^<extract_embedded_fonts^>1^</extract_embedded_fonts^>>>filters.js
echo.    ^</Parameters^>>>filters.js
echo.  ^</Filter^>>>filters.js
echo.^</filters^>>>filters.js
::mux it all up and burn the subs in
%avidemux% --video-codec %vcodec% --video-conf cbr=%vbr% --audio-codec %acodec% --audio-bitrate %abr% --force-alt-h264 --force-b-frame --filters "%%~dpF\filters.js" --load "%%F" --save "%%~dpnF%out%" --quit >> avidemux.log
del filters.js
)
```

It takes a few variables for configuration, then it extracts the `*.ass` subs using `mkvextract`, extracts up to 20 attachments from the `mkv` file to the current directory (which is where the `mkv` files reside and where the batch is run from). Then, via a method probably looked down upon by many, it creates a filters definition that avidemux should be able to use to apply the subtitle filter to the resulting video. Once that file exists, avidemux runs through it all.

However, avidemux fails. Here's avidemux.log:

```
*************************
  Avidemux v2.5.6
*************************
 http://www.avidemux.org
 Code      : Mean, JSC, Grant Pedersen
 GFX       : Nestor Di, nestordi@augcyl.org
 Design    : Jakub Misak
 FreeBSD   : Anish Mistry, amistry@am-productions.biz
 Audio     : Mihail Zenkov
 Mac OS X  : Kuisathaverat, Harry van der Wolf
 Win32     : Grant Pedersen

Compiler: GCC 4.6.2
Build Target: Microsoft Windows (x86)
User Interface: CLI
Operating System: Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate (6.1.7600; 64-bit)

Initialising prefs
Directory C:\Users\Suchipi\AppData\Roaming\avidemux exists.Good.
Using C:\Users\Suchipi\AppData\Roaming\avidemux as base directory for prefs/jobs/...
Preferences found and loaded
[cpuCaps]Checking CPU capabilities
        MMX detected 
        3DNOW detected 
        MMXEXT detected 
        SSE detected 
        SSE2 detected 
        SSE3 detected 
[cpuCaps]End of CPU capabilities check (cpuMask :ffffffff)
Initializing WinSock
WinSock ok

[Locale] setlocale English_United States.1252
[Locale] Textdomain was avidemux
[Locale] Textdomain is now avidemux
[Locale] Test: _File

Initializing Dithering tables
Initializing postproc
Deleting post proc
updating post proc
Enabled type:3 strength:3

 Registering Internal Filters
******************************

[ADM_ad_plugin] Scanning directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\audioDecoder\
[ADM_ad_plugin] Plugin loaded version 0.0.1, name libADM_ad_a52.dll, desc: LibAC3 decoder plugin for avidemux (c) Mean

[ADM_ad_plugin] Plugin loaded version 0.0.1, name libADM_ad_faad.dll, desc: Faad2 decoder plugin for avidemux (c) Mean

[ADM_ad_plugin] Plugin loaded version 0.0.1, name libADM_ad_Mad.dll, desc: LibMad decoder plugin for avidemux (c) Mean

[ADM_ad_plugin] Plugin loaded version 1.0.0, name libADM_ad_opencore_amrnb.dll, desc: opencore-amrnb decoder plugin for Avidemux (c) Mean/Gruntster

[ADM_ad_plugin] Plugin loaded version 1.0.0, name libADM_ad_opencore_amrwb.dll, desc: opencore-amrwb decoder plugin for Avidemux (c) Mean/Gruntster

[ADM_ad_plugin] Plugin loaded version 0.0.1, name libADM_ad_vorbis.dll, desc: libVorbis decoder plugin for avidemux (c) Mean

[ADM_ad_plugin] Scanning done, found 6 codec
[ADM_vf_plugin] Scanning directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_addborders.dll as Add black borders
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_asharp_cli.dll as asharp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_asharp_qt4.dll:WrongUI
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_avisynthResize_cli.dll as Resize
C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_avisynthResize_qt4.dll:WrongUI
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_blackenBorders.dll as Blacken borders
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_blendDgBob.dll as DG Bob
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_blendRemoval.dll as Blend Removal
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_chromashift_cli.dll as Chroma shift
C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_chromaShift_qt4.dll:WrongUI
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_cnr2_cli.dll as Cnr2
C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_cnr2_qt4.dll:WrongUI
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_colorYUV_cli.dll as Avisynth ColorYUV
C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_colorYUV_qt4.dll:WrongUI
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_contrast_cli.dll as Contrast
C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_contrast_qt4.dll:WrongUI
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_crop_cli.dll as Crop
C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_crop_qt4.dll:WrongUI
C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_curveEditor_qt4.dll:WrongUI
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_decimate.dll as Decomb Decimate
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_Deinterlace.dll as Deinterlace
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_Delta.dll as Luma delta
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_Denoise.dll as Denoise
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_denoise3d.dll as MPlayer denoise3d
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_denoise3dhq.dll as MPlayer hqdn3d
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_dropOut.dll as Drop
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_eq2_cli.dll as MPlayer eq2
C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_eq2_qt4.dll:WrongUI
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_equalizer_cli.dll as Luma equalizer
C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_equalizer_qt4.dll:WrongUI
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_fade.dll as Fade
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_fastconvolutiongauss.dll as Gauss smooth
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_fastconvolutionmean.dll as Mean
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_fastconvolutionmedian.dll as Median
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_fastconvolutionsharpen.dll as Sharpen
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_FluxSmooth.dll as FluxSmooth
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_forcedPP.dll as Forced postprocessing
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_Hue_cli.dll as MPlayer hue
C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_hue_qt4.dll:WrongUI
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_hzStackField.dll as Horizontal Stack Field
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_keepEvenField.dll as Keep even fields
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_keepOddField.dll as Keep odd fields
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_kernelDeint.dll as KernelDeint
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_largemedian.dll as Median (5x5)
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_lavDeinterlace.dll as libavcodec deinterlacer
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_lumaonly.dll as Luma only
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_mcdeint.dll as mcDeinterlace
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_mergeField.dll as Merge fields
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_Mosaic.dll as mosaic
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_mpdelogo_cli.dll as MPlayer delogo
C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_mpdelogo_qt4.dll:WrongUI
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_mplayerResize_cli.dll as MPlayer resize
C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_mplayerResize_qt4.dll:WrongUI
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_mSharpen.dll as MSharpen
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_mSmooth.dll as MSmooth by Donald Graft
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_palShift.dll as PAL field shift
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_Pulldown.dll as Pulldown
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_resampleFps.dll as Resample fps
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_reverse.dll as Reverse
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_rotate.dll as Rotate
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_separateField.dll as Separate Fields
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_smartPalShift.dll as PAL smart
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_smartSwapField.dll as Smart swap fields
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_soften.dll as Soften
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_ssa.dll as ASS
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_Stabilize.dll as Light denoiser.
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_stackField.dll as Stack fields
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_sub_cli.dll as Subtitler
C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_sub_qt4.dll:WrongUI
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_swapField.dll as Swap fields
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_swapuv.dll as Swap U and V
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_tdeint.dll as TDeint
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_telecide.dll as Decomb Telecide
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_Tisophote.dll as TIsophote
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_unstackField.dll as Unstack fields
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_vflip.dll as Vertical flip
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_vlad.dll as Temporal Cleaner
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_Whirl.dll as Whirl
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vf_yadif.dll as yadif
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vidChromaU.dll as Chroma U
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoFilter\/libADM_vidChromaV.dll as Chroma V
[ADM_vf_plugin] Scanning done
[ADM_av_plugin] Scanning directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\audioDevices\
Name :Win32 ApiVersion :1
[Filters] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\audioDevices\/libADM_av_win32.dll as  Win32 audio device (c) mean
[ADM_av_plugin] Scanning done
[ADM_ae_plugin] Scanning directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\audioEncoders\
[AudioEncoder] Loaded Aften version 01.00.00 wavTag :0x2000
[AudioEncoder] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\audioEncoders\/libADM_ae_aften.dll as  Aften AC3 encoder plugin Mean/Gruntster 2008
[AudioEncoder] Loaded Faac version 01.00.00 wavTag :0xff
[AudioEncoder] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\audioEncoders\/libADM_ae_faac.dll as  Faac AAC encoder plugin Mean 2008
[AudioEncoder] Loaded Lame version 01.00.00 wavTag :0x55
[AudioEncoder] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\audioEncoders\/libADM_ae_lame.dll as  Lame MP3 encoder plugin Mean 2008
[AudioEncoder] Loaded LavAC3 version 01.00.00 wavTag :0x2000
[AudioEncoder] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\audioEncoders\/libADM_ae_lav_ac3.dll as  AC3 LavEncoder encoder plugin Mean 2008
[AudioEncoder] Loaded LavMP2 version 01.00.00 wavTag :0x50
[AudioEncoder] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\audioEncoders\/libADM_ae_lav_mp2.dll as  MP2 LavCodec encoder plugin Mean 2008
[AudioEncoder] Loaded PCM version 01.00.00 wavTag :0x1
[AudioEncoder] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\audioEncoders\/libADM_ae_pcm.dll as  PCM encoder plugin Mean 2008
[AudioEncoder] Loaded TwoLame version 01.00.00 wavTag :0x50
[AudioEncoder] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\audioEncoders\/libADM_ae_twolame.dll as  TwoLame MP2 encoder plugin Mean 2008
[AudioEncoder] Loaded Vorbis version 01.00.00 wavTag :0x676f
[AudioEncoder] Registered filter C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\audioEncoders\/libADM_ae_vorbis.dll as  Vorbis encoder plugin Mean 2008
[ADM_ae_plugin] Scanning done
[ADM_ad_plugin] Scanning directory C:\Users\Suchipi\AppData\Roaming\avidemux\plugins\audioDecoder\
[ADM_ad_plugin] Cannot parse plugin
[ADM_vf_plugin] Scanning directory C:\Users\Suchipi\AppData\Roaming\avidemux\plugins\videoFilter\
[ADM_vf_plugin] Cannot parse plugin
[ADM_vidEnc_plugin] Scanning directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\plugins\videoEncoder\
ignored: avcodec
ignored: mpeg2enc
ignored: x264
ignored: xvid
[ADM_vidEnc_plugin] Plugin loaded version 1.5.0, filename libADM_vidEnc_avcodec.dll, desc: DV video encoder plugin for Avidemux (c) Mean/Gruntster
[ADM_vidEnc_plugin] Plugin loaded version 1.5.0, filename libADM_vidEnc_avcodec.dll, desc: Sorenson Spark video encoder plugin for Avidemux (c) Mean/Gruntster
[ADM_vidEnc_plugin] Plugin loaded version 1.5.0, filename libADM_vidEnc_avcodec.dll, desc: FFV1 video encoder plugin for Avidemux (c) Mean/Gruntster
[ADM_vidEnc_plugin] Plugin loaded version 1.5.0, filename libADM_vidEnc_avcodec.dll, desc: FFVHuff video encoder plugin for Avidemux (c) Mean/Gruntster
[ADM_vidEnc_plugin] Plugin loaded version 1.5.0, filename libADM_vidEnc_avcodec.dll, desc: H.263 video encoder plugin for Avidemux (c) Mean/Gruntster
[ADM_vidEnc_plugin] Plugin loaded version 1.5.0, filename libADM_vidEnc_avcodec.dll, desc: Huffyuv video encoder plugin for Avidemux (c) Mean/Gruntster
[ADM_vidEnc_plugin] Plugin loaded version 1.5.0, filename libADM_vidEnc_avcodec.dll, desc: M-JPEG video encoder plugin for Avidemux (c) Mean/Gruntster
[ADM_vidEnc_plugin] Plugin loaded version 1.5.0, filename libADM_vidEnc_avcodec.dll, desc: MPEG-1 video encoder plugin for Avidemux (c) Mean/Gruntster
[ADM_vidEnc_plugin] Plugin loaded version 1.5.0, filename libADM_vidEnc_avcodec.dll, desc: MPEG-2 video encoder plugin for Avidemux (c) Mean/Gruntster
[ADM_vidEnc_plugin] Plugin loaded version 1.5.0, filename libADM_vidEnc_avcodec.dll, desc: MPEG-4 ASP video encoder plugin for Avidemux (c) Mean/Gruntster
[ADM_vidEnc_plugin] Plugin loaded version 1.0.0, filename libADM_vidEnc_mpeg2enc.dll, desc: MPEG-1 video encoder plugin for Avidemux (c) Mean/Gruntster
[ADM_vidEnc_plugin] Plugin loaded version 1.0.0, filename libADM_vidEnc_mpeg2enc.dll, desc: MPEG-2 video encoder plugin for Avidemux (c) Mean/Gruntster
[ADM_vidEnc_plugin] Plugin loaded version 1.0.1, filename libADM_vidEnc_x264.dll, desc: x264 video encoder plugin for Avidemux (c) Mean/Gruntster
[Xvid] Initialising Xvid
[Xvid] Build: xvid-1.3.2
[Xvid] SIMD supported: (1ff)
        MMX
        MMXEXT
        SSE
        SSE2
        SSE3
        3DNOW
        3DNOWEXT
        ALTIVEC
[ADM_vidEnc_plugin] Plugin loaded version 1.0.1, filename libADM_vidEnc_xvid.dll, desc: Xvid video encoder plugin for Avidemux (c) Mean/Gruntster
[ADM_vidEnc_plugin] Scanning done, found 14 codec
[Win32] Creating audio device
Registered DialogFactory classes
Spidermonkey initialized.

 *** Automated : 48 entries*************
video-codec-->1

 Codec x264 found
video-conf-->1
Codec conf is cbr
audio-codec-->1
[AudioEncoder] Selected Aften for tag 8192 ()
audio-bitrate-->1

 Audio bitrate 320
force-alt-h264-->0
force-b-frame-->0
filters-->1

*********** EXCEPTION **************
Registers:
EAX: 00000000  EBX: 0028FC70  ECX: 00000220  EDX: 00000000  ESI: 0151A980
EDI: 00530F70  ESP: 0028FB78  EBP: 0028FC90  EIP: 0041C4AE  EFlags: 00210216

Exception Code: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (C0000005)
Exception Flags: 00000000

Origin:
vidHeader::getVideoInfo(aviInfo*) <+0xE>  [C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\avidemux2_cli.exe]
*********** EXCEPTION **************

*********** BACKTRACE **************
LdrRemoveLoadAsDataTable <+0x459>  [C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll]
KiUserExceptionDispatcher <+0xF>  [C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll]
filterLoadXml(char const*) <+0x17>  [C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\avidemux2_cli.exe]
printf <+0x67>  [C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll]
automation() <+0x24E>  [C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\avidemux2_cli.exe]
unlock <+0x15>  [C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll]
puts <+0x173>  [C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll]
__gnu_cxx::free_list::_M_clear() <+0x5FE>  [C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\libstdc++-6.dll]
RtlInitializeExceptionChain <+0x36>  [C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll]
unknown function <+0x36>  [C:\Program Files (x86)\Avidemux 2.5\avidemux2_cli.exe]
unknown function <+0x36>  [unknown module]
unknown function <+0x36>  [unknown module]
*********** BACKTRACE **************

Cleaning up
Deleting post proc
Waiting for Spidermonkey to finish...
Cleaning up Spidermonkey.
End of cleanup

Images stat:
___________
Max memory consumed (MB)     : 0
Current memory consumed (MB) : 0
Max image used               : 0
Cur image used               : 0
Global mem stat
______________
    Memory consumed: 0 (MB)

Goodbye...
```

Why is avidemux failing? How can I use this log to figure out where my error lies?